# How to use JavaScript in included components in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

In short, how to use JavaScript in the component that will be then included in the main page?

A standard approach in Django templates is to create a `base.html` template and then extend it. That base template usually has blocks like `content`, `extra_js`, and `extra_css`. The extended template looks like

```html
{% extend 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
   some content
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
# some js code here
{% endblock %}
```

I need to create a component that will be included on several pages and I need to use JavaScript inside that component. I know that it will be included only on pages that extend `base.html`, the page that includes it will look like

```html
{% extend 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
   {% include 'component.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
# some js code here
{% endblock %}
```

However, `component.html` knows nothing about `extra_js` block because it doesn't extend `base.html`, I cannot use that block in `component.html`, and if I just put some JavaScript code in it then after the template is rendered any JavaScript in `component.html` will end up being in the middle of the body of the document, will be executed before libraries like jQuery are imported and will not work. What is the right way to work around it?